# Using a Perl one-liner in a shell script

Tags: bash, perl, shell, debian

This has been frustrating me for hours now. I wrote a simple wrapper around a Perl one-liner to update the serials in some DNS zone files.

I feel compelled to add this:- Don't offer other ways to do this, OK? It's about why this won't work, not about how to achieve the result by other means.

Here is my simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
#loop through the supplied files updating the timestamp (serial)
SERIAL=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`;
for name in $@
do
saCMD="'s/^(\W*)\d*.*;\W*serial/\${1}$SERIAL ; serial/g'"
#echo the command 
echo "perl -pi -e "$saCMD" $name"
#execute the command
`perl -pi -e $saCMD $name`
done
```

I have tried a multitude of different ways and it fails silently or with the message

> Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1..

If I execute the echoed command it works faultlessly

I am on a Debian 7 system

Can anyone point out me to why this is not executing as I would expect it to?

#### EDIT:

Some example data

```
$TTL 300
domain.org. IN SOA     ns1.domain.com. admin.domain.org. (
                2014090914      ; serial, todays date+todays
                7200            ; refresh, seconds
                7200            ; retry, seconds
                2419200         ; expire, seconds
                3600 )          ; minimum, seconds
```

The line of interest is `2014090914      ; serial, todays date+todays`

Comment: Out of interest - does it work if you omit the backticks? Reason I ask - backticks will spawn a subshell which I think might be unwrapping another layer of your quotes.

Comment: The backticks make no *obvious* difference.

Comment: Odd. Because inlining the backticks like that should result in executing whatever the output of that perl command is.

Comment: Doesnt it just return the output to the script? like how I have formatted the timestamp? as the perl is not returning an error there is no output. This same command worked flawlessly on Centos. ( I havent tested lately though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least a quoting issue. You make the single quotes a part of the `saCMD="'s...'"`. They will not be removed by the shell but passed to perl, as you can see in the `echo` output.

In addition,

```
#execute the command
`perl -pi -e $saCMD $name`
```

has likely useless backticks. Or do you also want to run a command that's being output by the perl script? To debug shell scripts, place `set -x` at the beginning.

This works here:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERIAL=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
for name in "$@"; do
  saCMD="s/^(\W*)\d*.*;\W*serial/\${1}$SERIAL ; serial/"
  perl -pi -e "$saCMD" "$name"
done
```

and turns your example data into

```
$TTL 300
domain.org. IN SOA     ns1.domain.com. admin.domain.org. (
                201508201330 ; serial, todays date+todays
                7200            ; refresh, seconds
                7200            ; retry, seconds
                2419200         ; expire, seconds
                3600 )          ; minimum, seconds
```

Comment: I am aware the backticks are mostly superfluous. I wondered if it changed the way the command was interpreted..The single quotes are meant to be passed to the perl application that is the 'script' perl is executing. without the single quotes it would be treated as multiple variables

Comment: Thanks for the hint with set -x. it outputs the command. which does work if I run it directly on the commandline. but not from within the shell script

Comment: Ok I now see what was happening. As it was effectively quoted twice Perl was not recognising it as a regex. Yay.

Answer (score 0):

Proper quoting should help. You haven't shown the input data, so I can't test:

```
saCMD="s/^(\W*)\d*.*;\W*serial/\${1}$SERIAL ; serial/g" # No inner quotes.
perl -pi -e "$saCMD" "$name"
```

Also, `/g` seems pointless as the regex only matches at the beginning of the string (`^`).

Comment: I have tried multiple different regex's originally it wasn't matching the start. What is confusing is if I echo the command and run that directly from the commandline it works exactly as it should.

Comment: @DeveloperChris That's because when cut/pasting the echoed command, you pass it a second time to the shell, which performs quote removal once more and strips the single quotes before invoking perl. It's like the difference in `echo "''"` and `echo ''`.

Comment: @Jens Yes it does remove the single quotes but only after it has assigned the string to an argument otherwise the string would be broken up into many arguments. Whether the script is called from within a shell script or from the commandline it still needs the quotes. I have tried both ways to be sure.